# Obtener Latitud y Longitud con places SDK en Android Studio

Tags: android, geolocalización, google-places

perdonad pues somos novatos.
Estamos tratando de obtener latitud y longitud de una dirección en Google Places SDK, pero solo conseguimos obtener la dirección, hemos buscado, que es utilizando getLat y getLng, pero o no sabemos donde colocarlo o lo ponemos erroneamente.
Muchas gracias de antemanos

//JAVA ACTIVITY

```
package com.example.fl.trabajomapa;

//PARTE CODIGO AUTOOMPLETE
@Override
public void onConnectionFailed(@NonNull ConnectionResult connectionResult) {

}


private static final String TAGGOOGLE = "GoogleActivity";
private static final int RC_SIGN_IN = 1;
private int STORAGE_PERMISSION_CODE= 1;//Para los permisos

final private int REQUEST_CODE_ASK_PERMISSIONS = 111;

private static final String TAG = "CAPublicaOfertaActivity";

//COORDENADAS ENTRE LAS QUE BUSCA EL AUTOCOMPLETE
private static final LatLngBounds LAT_LNG_BOUNDS = new LatLngBounds(
        new LatLng(27.666172, -18.273932), new LatLng(42.772283, 4.747570));

//PARTE CODIGO AUTOOMPLETE
AutoCompleteTextView etdireccionnegocioAutoCA;
PlaceAutocompleteAdapter mPlaceAutocompleteAdapter;
GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;

//DECLARO VARIANTES
TextView tvocultolatitudCA, tvocultolongitudCA, tvocultoCA;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_capublicar_oferta);


    // AUTOCOMPLETE
    etdireccionnegocioAutoCA = (AutoCompleteTextView) findViewById(R.id.etdireccionnegocioAutoCA);
    //INICIAR PROCESO AUTOOMPLETE
    init();



    //ENLAZO VARIANTES

    tvocultolatitudCA = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvocultolatitudCA);
    tvocultolongitudCA = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvocultolongitudCA);
    tvocultoCA = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvocultoCA);

}//FIN ONCREATE


//BOTON OBTENER DIRECCION
public void obtenerdireccion (View view){
    locationStart();
}

//MANDAR OFERTA
public void publicaroferta(View view) {

    //ENLAZO VARIANTES CAMPOS OBLIGATORIOS

    String direccionnegocioCA = etdireccionnegocioAutoCA.getText().toString();
    String latitudnegocioCA = tvocultolatitudCA.getText().toString();
    //TODO es double porque tiene decimales so retraso de hombre
    //Double latitudint = Double.parseDouble(latitudnegocioCA);
    String longitudnegocioCA = tvocultolongitudCA.getText().toString();
    //Double longitudint = Double.parseDouble(longitudnegocioCA);

}


//PROTOCOLO PARA OBTENER DIRECCION ▼
private void locationStart() {
    LocationManager mlocManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    Localizacion Local = new Localizacion();
    Local.setMainActivity(this);
    final boolean gpsEnabled = mlocManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
    if (!gpsEnabled) {
        Intent settingsIntent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);
        startActivity(settingsIntent);
    }
    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION,}, 1000);
        return;
    }
    mlocManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 0, 0, (LocationListener) Local);
    mlocManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, (LocationListener) Local);
    tvocultoCA.setText("Localizacion agregada");


}

public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions, int[] grantResults) {
    if (requestCode == 1000) {
        if (grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            locationStart();
            return;
        }
    }
}

public void setLocation(Location loc) {
    //OBTENER LA DIRECCION DE LA CALLE A PARTIR DE LA LATITUD Y LA LONGITUD
    if (loc.getLatitude() != 0.0 && loc.getLongitude() != 0.0) {
        try {
            Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(this, Locale.getDefault());
            List<Address> list = geocoder.getFromLocation(
                    loc.getLatitude(), loc.getLongitude(), 1);

            //004


            if (!list.isEmpty()) {
                Address DirCalle = list.get(0);
                etdireccionnegocioAutoCA.setText(DirCalle.getAddressLine(0));

            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}


//COMIENZA GESTION DE LOCALIZACION
public class Localizacion implements LocationListener {
    CAPublicarOfertaActivity CAPublicarOfertaActivity;

    public CAPublicarOfertaActivity getCAPublicarOfertaActivity() {
        return CAPublicarOfertaActivity;
    }

    public void setMainActivity(CAPublicarOfertaActivity CAPublicarOfertaActivity) {
        this.CAPublicarOfertaActivity = CAPublicarOfertaActivity;
    }

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location loc) {

        // ESTE METODO SE EJECUTA CADA VEZ QUE EL GPS RECIBE NUEVAS COORDENADAS DEBIDO A LA DETECCION DE UN CAMBIO DE UBICACION
        loc.getLatitude();
        loc.getLongitude();
        String Text = "Lat = " + loc.getLatitude() + "\n Long = " + loc.getLongitude();
        tvocultoCA.setText(Text);
        this.CAPublicarOfertaActivity.setLocation(loc);
    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
        // AVISO DE GPS DESACTIVADO
        tvocultoCA.setText("GPS Desactivado");
    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {

        // AVISO DE GPS ACTIVO
        tvocultoCA.setText("GPS Activado");
    }

    @Override
    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
        switch (status) {
            case LocationProvider.AVAILABLE:
                Log.d("debug", "LocationProvider.AVAILABLE");
                break;
            case LocationProvider.OUT_OF_SERVICE:
                Log.d("debug", "LocationProvider.OUT_OF_SERVICE");
                break;
            case LocationProvider.TEMPORARILY_UNAVAILABLE:
                Log.d("debug", "LocationProvider.TEMPORARILY_UNAVAILABLE");
                break;

            //PROTOCOLO PARA OBTENER DIRECCION ▲
        }
    }
}


//PROTOCOLO AUTOCOMPLETE
private void init() {
    Log.d(TAG, "init: initializing");

    mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient
            .Builder(this)
            .addApi(Places.GEO_DATA_API)
            .addApi(Places.PLACE_DETECTION_API)
            .enableAutoManage(this, this)
            .build();

    mPlaceAutocompleteAdapter = new PlaceAutocompleteAdapter(this, mGoogleApiClient,
            LAT_LNG_BOUNDS, null);

    etdireccionnegocioAutoCA.setAdapter(mPlaceAutocompleteAdapter);


    etdireccionnegocioAutoCA.setOnEditorActionListener(new TextView.OnEditorActionListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onEditorAction(TextView textView, int actionId, KeyEvent keyEvent) {
            if (actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_SEARCH
                    || actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE
                    || keyEvent.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN
                    || keyEvent.getAction() == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER) {

            }

            return false;
        }
    });

    hideSoftKeyboard();
}

private void hideSoftKeyboard(){
    this.getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_HIDDEN);
}
```

//ADAPTER

```
package com.example.fl.trabajomapa;
```

public class PlaceAutocompleteAdapter
        extends ArrayAdapter implements Filterable {

```
private static final String TAG = "PlaceAutoCompleteAd";
private static final CharacterStyle STYLE_BOLD = new StyleSpan(Typeface.BOLD);
 private ArrayList<AutocompletePrediction> mResultList;
private GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;
private LatLngBounds mBounds;
private AutocompleteFilter mPlaceFilter;
public PlaceAutocompleteAdapter(Context context, GoogleApiClient googleApiClient,
                                LatLngBounds bounds, AutocompleteFilter filter) {
    super(context, android.R.layout.simple_expandable_list_item_2, android.R.id.text1);
    mGoogleApiClient = googleApiClient;
    mBounds = bounds;
    mPlaceFilter = filter;
}
public void setBounds(LatLngBounds bounds) {
    mBounds = bounds;
}
@Override
public int getCount() {
    return mResultList.size();
}
@Override
public AutocompletePrediction getItem(int position) {
    return mResultList.get(position);
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View row = super.getView(position, convertView, parent);


    AutocompletePrediction item = getItem(position);

    TextView textView1 = (TextView) row.findViewById(android.R.id.text1);
    TextView textView2 = (TextView) row.findViewById(android.R.id.text2);
    textView1.setText(item.getPrimaryText(STYLE_BOLD));
    textView2.setText(item.getSecondaryText(STYLE_BOLD));

    return row;
}

@Override
public Filter getFilter() {
    return new Filter() {
        @Override
        protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {
            FilterResults results = new FilterResults();

            ArrayList<AutocompletePrediction> filterData = new ArrayList<>();

            if (constraint != null) {
                filterData = getAutocomplete(constraint);
            }

            results.values = filterData;
            if (filterData != null) {
                results.count = filterData.size();
            } else {
                results.count = 0;
            }

            return results;
        }

        @Override
        protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint, FilterResults results) {

            if (results != null && results.count > 0) {
                mResultList = (ArrayList<AutocompletePrediction>) results.values;
                notifyDataSetChanged();
            } else {
                notifyDataSetInvalidated();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public CharSequence convertResultToString(Object resultValue) {
            if (resultValue instanceof AutocompletePrediction) {
                return ((AutocompletePrediction) resultValue).getFullText(null);
            } else {
                return super.convertResultToString(resultValue);
            }
        }
    };
}
private ArrayList<AutocompletePrediction> getAutocomplete(CharSequence constraint) {
    if (mGoogleApiClient.isConnected()) {
        Log.i(TAG, "Starting autocomplete query for: " + constraint);

        PendingResult<AutocompletePredictionBuffer> results =
                Places.GeoDataApi
                        .getAutocompletePredictions(mGoogleApiClient, constraint.toString(),
                                mBounds, mPlaceFilter);

        AutocompletePredictionBuffer autocompletePredictions = results
                .await(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

        final Status status = autocompletePredictions.getStatus();
        if (!status.isSuccess()) {
            Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Error contacting API: " + status.toString(),
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            Log.e(TAG, "Error getting autocomplete prediction API call: " + status.toString());
            autocompletePredictions.release();
            return null;
        }

        Log.i(TAG, "Query completed. Received " + autocompletePredictions.getCount()
                + " predictions.");

        return DataBufferUtils.freezeAndClose(autocompletePredictions);
    }
    Log.e(TAG, "Google API client is not connected for autocomplete query.");
    return null;
}
```

Comment: Pero si ya lo teneis - en la línea `List<Address> list = geocoder.getFromLocation(loc.getLatitude(), loc.getLongitude(), 1);` ya lo haceis. No sé qué mas quereis obtener. Latitud y longitud son de Location.

Comment: Buenas, muchas gracias por responder tan rápido, necesitamos recoger la Latitud en un textView y la Longitud en otros para subir a Firebase. Muchas gracias de antemano.

Comment: Perdona por la confusión, ese es el que obtenemos la geolocalización, por GPS y ese nos funciona, el que no nos funciona es el que emplea Google Places con texto autocompletar.

Comment: ¿Y no se puede asignar el valor a TextView desde el método setLocation? Es decir desde donde se obtienen latitud y longitud.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Somos los mismo que hemos formulado la pregunta, hemos encontrado la solución, la pongo por aquí por si alguien tiene el mismo problema en el futuro.
Simplemente le hemos añadido en el metodo publicaroferta un try and catch en el que pillamos la dirección y con el Geocoder obtenemos la latitud y la longitud

```
public void publicaroferta(View view) {

try {
        String direccionnegocioCA = etdireccionnegocioAutoCA.getText().toString();

        List<Address> addressList = geocoder.getFromLocationName(
                direccionnegocioCA, 5);
        if (addressList != null && addressList.size() > 0) {
            Double lat = (Double) (addressList.get(0).getLatitude() );
            Double lng = (Double) (addressList.get(0).getLongitude() );
            String latitudint = Double.toString(lat);
            tvocultolatitudCA.setText(latitudint);
            String longitudint = Double.toString(lng);
            tvocultolongitudCA.setText(longitudint);
        }
    }catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } 

//ENLAZO VARIANTES CAMPOS OBLIGATORIOS

String direccionnegocioCA = etdireccionnegocioAutoCA.getText().toString();
String latitudnegocioCA = tvocultolatitudCA.getText().toString();
Double latitudint = Double.parseDouble(latitudnegocioCA);
String longitudnegocioCA = tvocultolongitudCA.getText().toString();
Double longitudint = Double.parseDouble(longitudnegocioCA);
```

}

Tambien hemos tenido que llamar a Geocoder antes del onCreate con "Geocoder geocoder = null;" y dentro del onCreate con "geocoder = new Geocoder(this);". Espero que os sea de ayuda a los que vengais aqui.

Answer (score 0):

Supongo que esto ya lo tienes pero es importante comentar que primeramente para usar `Google Places` debes activar la API y

https://developers.google.com/places/android-sdk/signup

definir la `API KEY` en tu archivo `AndroidManifest.xml` :

```
<meta-data android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY" android:value="XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX" /> </application>
```

---

Al usar Places se obtienen lugares, pero para obtener los datos de geolocalización de el lugar seleccionado debes agregar un callback.

Usa `PlaceAutocomplete` en lugar de `AutocompletePrediction` y además agrega un holder a tu adapter:

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Typeface;
import android.text.style.CharacterStyle;
import android.text.style.StyleSpan;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Filter;
import android.widget.Filterable;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.PendingResult;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.Status;
import com.google.android.gms.location.places.AutocompleteFilter;
import com.google.android.gms.location.places.AutocompletePrediction;
import com.google.android.gms.location.places.AutocompletePredictionBuffer;
import com.google.android.gms.location.places.Places;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLngBounds;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

public class PlaceAutocompleteAdapter extends ArrayAdapter implements Filterable {

    private static final String TAG = "PlaceAutoCompleteAd";
    private static final CharacterStyle STYLE_BOLD = new StyleSpan(Typeface.BOLD);
    private ArrayList<PlaceAutocomplete> mResultList;
    private GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;
    private LatLngBounds mBounds;
    private AutocompleteFilter mPlaceFilter;

    public PlaceAutocompleteAdapter(Context context, GoogleApiClient googleApiClient,
                                    LatLngBounds bounds, AutocompleteFilter filter) {
        super(context, android.R.layout.simple_expandable_list_item_2, android.R.id.text1);
        mGoogleApiClient = googleApiClient;
        mBounds = bounds;
        mPlaceFilter = filter;
    }

    public void setBounds(LatLngBounds bounds) {
        mBounds = bounds;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mResultList.size();
    }

    @Override
    public PlaceAutocomplete getItem(int position) {
        return mResultList.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View row = super.getView(position, convertView, parent);


        PlaceAutocomplete item = getItem(position);

        TextView textView1 = (TextView) row.findViewById(android.R.id.text1);
        TextView textView2 = (TextView) row.findViewById(android.R.id.text2);
        textView1.setText(item.getPrimaryText(STYLE_BOLD));
        textView2.setText(item.getSecondaryText(STYLE_BOLD));

        return row;
    }

    @Override
    public Filter getFilter() {
        return new Filter() {
            @Override
            protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {
                FilterResults results = new FilterResults();

                ArrayList<PlaceAutocomplete> filterData = new ArrayList<>();

                if (constraint != null) {
                    filterData = getAutocomplete(constraint);
                }

                results.values = filterData;
                if (filterData != null) {
                    results.count = filterData.size();
                } else {
                    results.count = 0;
                }

                return results;
            }

            @Override
            protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint, FilterResults results) {

                if (results != null && results.count > 0) {
                    mResultList = (ArrayList<PlaceAutocomplete>) results.values;
                    notifyDataSetChanged();
                } else {
                    notifyDataSetInvalidated();
                }
            }

            @Override
            public CharSequence convertResultToString(Object resultValue) {
                if (resultValue instanceof AutocompletePrediction) {
                    return ((AutocompletePrediction) resultValue).getFullText(null);
                } else {
                    return super.convertResultToString(resultValue);
                }
            }
        };
    }

    private ArrayList<PlaceAutocomplete> getAutocomplete(CharSequence constraint) {
        if (mGoogleApiClient.isConnected()) {
            Log.i(TAG, "Starting autocomplete query for: " + constraint);

            PendingResult<AutocompletePredictionBuffer> results =
                    Places.GeoDataApi
                            .getAutocompletePredictions(mGoogleApiClient, constraint.toString(),
                                    mBounds, mPlaceFilter);

            AutocompletePredictionBuffer autocompletePredictions = results
                    .await(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

            final Status status = autocompletePredictions.getStatus();
            if (!status.isSuccess()) {
                Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Error contacting API: " + status.toString(),
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                Log.e(TAG, "Error getting autocomplete prediction API call: " + status.toString());
                autocompletePredictions.release();
                return null;
            }

            Log.i(TAG, "Query completed. Received " + autocompletePredictions.getCount()
                    + " predictions.");

           // return DataBufferUtils.freezeAndClose(autocompletePredictions);

            Iterator<AutocompletePrediction> iterator = autocompletePredictions.iterator();
            ArrayList resultList = new ArrayList<>(autocompletePredictions.getCount());
            while (iterator.hasNext()) {
                AutocompletePrediction prediction = iterator.next();
                // Get the details of this prediction and copy it into a new PlaceAutocomplete object.
                resultList.add(new PlaceAutocomplete(prediction.getPlaceId(),
                        prediction.getDescription()));
            }
            // Release the buffer now that all data has been copied.
            autocompletePredictions.release();
            return resultList;

        }
        Log.e(TAG, "Google API client is not connected for autocomplete query.");
        return null;
    }

    /**
     * Holder for GeoData Autocomplete API results.
     */
    class PlaceAutocomplete {
        public CharSequence placeId;
        public CharSequence description;
        PlaceAutocomplete(CharSequence placeId, CharSequence description) {
            this.placeId = placeId;
            this.description = description;
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return description.toString();
        }

    }
```

Ahora, agrega un listener a tu `AutoCompleteTextView` y mediante un `ResultCallback` puedes obtener el valor de la gelocalización:

```
   etdireccionnegocioAutoCA.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

            final PlaceAutocompleteAdapter.PlaceAutocomplete item = mPlaceAutocompleteAdapter.getItem(position);
            final String placeId = String.valueOf(item.placeId);
            Log.i(TAG, "Autocomplete item selected: " + item.description);


            PendingResult<PlaceBuffer> results = Places.GeoDataApi
                    .getPlaceById(mGoogleApiClient, placeId);

            results.setResultCallback(new ResultCallback<PlaceBuffer>() {
                @Override
                public void onResult(PlaceBuffer places) {
                    if (!places.getStatus().isSuccess()) {
                        // Request did not complete successfully
                        Log.e(TAG, "Place query did not complete. Error: " + places.getStatus().toString());
                        places.release();
                        return;
                    }
                    // Get the Place object from the buffer.
                    final Place place = places.get(0);
                    Log.i(TAG, "*Place (pick-up) latitude: " + place.getLatLng().latitude + " longitude: " + place.getLatLng().latitude);
                    start = place.getLatLng();
                }
            });

        }
    });
```

Te sugiero revisar este ejemplo, ahí puedes ver en el LogCat como registro los valores de Geolocalización al seleccionar los puntos de inicio y terminación:

[Android Route Google Maps](https://github.com/Jorgesys/Android-Route-Google-Maps/)

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Gracias por respondernos, mientras esperabamos estuvimos buscando informacion en otras páginas y encontramos le solución así que no hemos llegado a probar tu método, ahora pondré como lo hemos solucionado por si alguien necesita solucionar un problema parecido